# Using ratios to make drawing fit on iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibezierpath, cgpoint

I'm trying to draw an (American) football field for both an iPad and iPhone device using `UIBezierPath`, by drawing 12 horizontal lines, two of which mark the beginning of the endzone.

As you can see from below, the first line starts at the far left of the screen (0) and 1/12 of the way down, and extends all the way across (size.bounds.size.width) horizontally. The next line starts at the far left but 2/12 `CGPointMake(0, self.bounds.size.height / 12 *2 )`of the way down the view etc. It is calculated in this way for all 12 lines.  I thought, since I was setting the lines using formulas (i.e. self.bounds.size.height/ 12) rather than hard numbers that the whole field would fit on the view no matter what size screen I was using on either device (iPad or iPhone).

It works that way on iPad, however, when I view it on the iPhone, it shows one endzone at the top of the iPad screen but then only extends to the 20 yard line at the bottom (in portrait view). The situation is even worse when I view it in the smaller iPhone screen (3.5 inch) in that it only extends to about the 30 yard line at the bottom of the portrait view.

Why isn't it  happening the way I planned?

Update: the code below is in the `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method in a subclass of UIView, called FieldView. I connected the UIView to the main view controller as a property  `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FieldView *fieldView;`, and call `[self.fieldView setNeedsDisplay]` in the view controller so that `drawRect` in FieldView is run.

Update 2

The heights for these three lines are

```
2014-04-14 21:47:26.783 qbgeo[2189:a0b] height 85.333336   self.bounds.size.height / 12
2014-04-14 21:47:26.785 qbgeo[2189:a0b] height 170.666672  self.bounds.size.height / 12 * 2
2014-04-14 21:47:26.788 qbgeo[2189:a0b] height 256.000000  self.bounds.size.height / 12 * 3

UIBezierPath *goalLine = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[goalLine moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.bounds.size.height / 12)];
[goalLine addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height / 12)];
[[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
goalLine.lineWidth = kActivationInset2;
[goalLine strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5]; 

UIBezierPath *tenYardLine = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[tenYardLine moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.bounds.size.height / 12 *2 )];
[tenYardLine addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height / 12 * 2)];
[[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
tenYardLine.lineWidth = kActivationInset2;
[tenYardLine strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5];

UIBezierPath *twentyYardLine = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[twentyYardLine moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.bounds.size.height / 12 *3 )];
[twentyYardLine addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height / 12 * 3)];
[[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
twentyYardLine.lineWidth = kActivationInset2;
[twentyYardLine strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5];
```

Comment: Where is this code being executed?

Comment: @MichaelKing I updated the OP with more information about that.

Comment: Try logging the heights you are creating, and tell us what they are.

Comment: @MichaelKing updated op again, thanks

Comment: The code works fine when I do it on an iPhone or iPad (and you really should use a for loop instead of repeating that code 12 times).

Comment: @redelmar you can see both endzones? can it just be the simulator then? thanks for the loop suggestion

Comment: Yes I see both end zones in the simulator as well. There should only be 11 lines though, not 12.

Comment: Thanks, it's not working that way for me in the simulator. Yes, you're right about the number of lines. (My extra line just gets hidden at the bottom of the screen however for anyone else reading this question that's not the reason for the problem in the OP, i just couldn't count properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked fine for me. Try it and see if it works in your hands,

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    for (int i =1; i<12; i++) {
        UIBezierPath *line = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
        [line moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.bounds.size.height / 12 * i)];
        [line addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height / 12 * i)];
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
        line.lineWidth = (i==1 || i==11)? 3 : 1;
        [line strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me the loop. There's other code that has to go into drawRect to complete the field (such as positioning the numbers to straddle the lines, like in NFL), but this part's obviously much nicer in a loop and I appreciate the attention to detail with the thicker goal lines. Sadly on my simulator still doesn't show the whole field for iPhone.

Comment: by the way, since you have the code already set up, you might know the answer to this question about putting the numbers on the field to straddle the lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085332/plotting-graphics-location-in-relation-to-other-graphics

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil, did you solve the problem of not seeing the whole field?