# plotting graphics location in relation to other graphics

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making this https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDd7W.jpg NFL style football field for an iPad/iOS app. The horizontal lines are created with this code in drawRect in a subclass of a UIView

```
 for (int i =1; i<12; i++) {
        UIBezierPath *line = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
        [line moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.bounds.size.height / 12 * i)];
        [line addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height / 12 * i)];
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
        line.lineWidth = (i==1 || i==11)? 3 : 1;
        [line strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5];
    }
```

The numbers are created with this code (for example, the ten yard line at the top)

```
 UILabel * tenYardLineRight = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width / 3 * 2, self.bounds.size.height /  11 * 1.6, 50.0, 36.0) ];
    tenYardLineRight.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
    tenYardLineRight.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //    scoreLabel4.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tenYardLineRight.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(36.0)];
    [self addSubview:tenYardLineRight];
    tenYardLineRight.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"10"];
    tenYardLineRight.alpha = 0.5;
    tenYardLineRight.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(270 * M_PI / 180.0);

    UILabel *tenYardLineLeft = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width / 4 , self.bounds.size.height /  11 * 1.6 , 50, 36.0) ];
    tenYardLineLeft.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
    tenYardLineLeft.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //    scoreLabel3.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tenYardLineLeft.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(36.0)];
    [self addSubview:tenYardLineLeft];
    tenYardLineLeft.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"10"];
    tenYardLineLeft.alpha = 0.5;
    tenYardLineLeft.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90 * M_PI / 180.0);
```

The trickiest part is getting the numbers to straddle the horizontal lines.  For the 10 yard line, I did that by setting the y position like this

```
self.bounds.size.height /  11 * 1.6
```

For the twenty yard line, I did it like this

```
self.bounds.size.height /  11 * 2.5
```

So you can see a pattern developing. Thirty yard line like this

```
 self.bounds.size.height /  11 * 3.4
```

However, the 40 yard line broke the pattern

```
self.bounds.size.height /  11 * 4.4     //I expected it to be 4.3
```

This was the fifty yard line

```
self.bounds.size.height /  11 * 5.3
```

As I progress down the field, from top to bottom, there is another set of numbers like the 30/40 yard line problem, where the decimal ends with the same number whereas an increment is expected of some kind.

I'm not sure if this is a result of poor graphics on the simulator (I don't have a developer license currently).

Is there a way to define the numbers in relation to the horizontal lines so it doesn't depend on my trial and error, or is there some other way to put this in a loop (which the pattern breaking seems to prevent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a much simpler way by using the point you already have (the starting point of each of your lines) as a place to draw the text. The point needs to be adjusted for the size of the font, and the way strings are drawn. Here is a way to do it,

```
@interface RDView ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *markers;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *dict;
@end

@implementation RDView


-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        _markers = @[@" G",@"10",@"20",@"30",@"40",@"50",@"40",@"30",@"20",@"10",@" G"];
        _dict = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor yellowColor]};
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    for (int i =1; i<12; i++) {
        UIBezierPath *line = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
        CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.bounds.size.height / 12 * i);
        NSString *marker =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:self.markers[i-1]];
        [self drawVerticalText:marker withContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() atPoint:startPoint];
        [line moveToPoint:startPoint];
        [line addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height / 12 * i)];
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
        line.lineWidth = (i==1 || i==11)? 3 : 1;
        [line strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5];
    }
}


- (void)drawVerticalText:(NSString *)marker  withContext:(CGContextRef)context atPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    CGFloat wOffset = [marker sizeWithAttributes:self.dict].width;
    CGFloat hOffset = [marker sizeWithAttributes:self.dict].height/2;
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, point.y );
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI_2);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -point.y);
    [marker drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(point.x - hOffset, point.y - wOffset) withAttributes:self.dict];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

This code produces this result,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for showing me the calculation you did, which I applied to my existing code. I didn't use your code exactly because I couldn't figure out how to rotate the attributed strings. I'm not able to do this with an attributed string. `tenYardLineLeft.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90 * M_PI / 180.0);` If you can update your answer to show that, I'd really appreciate it but don't worry if you can't. One reason why I prefer your solution is that it doesn't use so many labels/subviews, so maybe it's fewer objects in memory?

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil, I have a method to rotate the text, but it's not quite ready to post yet. I'll post that soon.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil, I've updated my code with a method to rotate the text. I don't have a lot of experience with Quartz drawing, so if anyone has suggestions of how to improve this, I'd like to see them.